# Receive Name error while trying to call wicked wizard steps

Tags: ruby, rubygems, wizard, railscasts

I try to reproduce http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked railscast. I try to create report in four steps wizard. I

1. generate controller report_steps
2. add **resources :report_steps** to routes.rb
3. create steps views

Now I try to call it(like in railscats by typing  ***localhost:3000/report_steps/step1*** in address bar in browser) and receive:

```
Routing Error

uninitialized constant ReportStepsController::Wicked
```

What is the problem?
I use ruby 1.9 2 and rails 3.0.12.

**UPD:** after commenting and uncommenting **include Wicked::Wizard** behaviour changed(it's a kind of magic) and now I receive new error:

```
NameError in ReportStepsController#show

uninitialized constant ReportStep
```

Comment: Said Kaldybaev: doesn't help.

Comment: Have you got an authentication `load_and_authorize_resource` at the top of your controller?

Comment: Take that out and it'll work.

Comment: i have the same problem, the solution for me is to restart the server

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are missing something in/with your model. Do you have a model `Report`?

Also could you post the related code (controller, model, eventually helpers) on here? That would help a lot finding the point where constant `ReportStep` is actually used.